# Google Analytics Events Tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics

I've being tried to install google events tracking on several sites but with no luck. I really want to know why its not working.

I installed events tracking on this site http://bedsndrinks.com/, the second "Book Now" button, here is the code I added to the button onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘book form’, ‘click’, ‘book now’);“
I tried to use Google Analytics Debugger, but I don't see any "event" hitType. one thing I noticed is that the tracking code looks okay in source code but different when I inspect it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check how your onclick is being rendered. When I loaded the page I saw the following:

```
<input id="sendBook" type="submit" value="Book Now" 
onclick="”ga(‘send’," ‘event’,="" ‘book="" form’,="" ‘click’,="" now’);“="">
```

As you stated in your question, the format should be as below:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'book form', 'click', 'book now');
```